# Dependent destroy to tables with more than one references

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a table Atribuition with 2 references from User table.

```
class Attribuition < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'user_id'
  belongs_to :not_rated, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'not_rated_id'
end
```

The User model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :attribuitions, dependent: :destroy
end
```

When i destroy an user marked in not_rated i want it to be destroyed, but it just happens when i destroied an user marked as user_id, then the attribute row is deleted. I wanna make dependent:: destroy to work for many references of same model. That is possible?

My migration is:

```
class CreateAttribuitions < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :attribuitions do |t|
      t.references :user
      t.references :not_rated, index: { unique: true }

      t.timestamps
    end

  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**

First you do following change as rails use **convention over configuration**

```
class Attribuition < ApplicationRecord
-  belongs_to :user, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'user_id'
+  belongs_to :user
end
```

**Changes needed**

When you mention `has_many :attribuitions, dependent: :destroy` by side of `User` model `class_name` will be `Attribuition` and foreign_key will be `user_id` stored in `attributions` table.

So if you need to destroy `attribuitions` related by foreign_key `not_rated_id` & `user_id` then you need following changes.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :attribuitions, dependent: :destroy # default foreign_key is user_id
  has_many :not_rated_attribuitions, foreign_key: 'not_rated_id', dependent: :destroy
end
```